# Adding more schedulers

Tags: ubuntu, scheduling

I have seen different IO schedulers in tutorials, e.g. cfq, noop, but when I test on my linux, I don't see them.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
$ uname -r
5.13.0-27-generic
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I would like to know if I can do anything more to see more schedulers. Any thought?

UPDATE:

Based on the suggestion, I see the following IOSCHED values

```
$ grep IOSCHED  /boot/config-5.13.0-27-generic
CONFIG_MQ_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_MQ_IOSCHED_KYBER=m
CONFIG_IOSCHED_BFQ=m
CONFIG_BFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED=y
```

Also, there are two modules in `/lib/modules`:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/block/
bfq.ko  kyber-iosched.ko
```

When I load the modules, I don't see bfq in the list.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none
$ sudo modprobe kyber-iosched bfq
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] kyber none
```

Is that a correct output?

Answer (score 1):

In most distribution kernels, other schedulers are available, but they need to be loaded; for example

```
sudo modprobe kyber-iosched
sudo modprobe bfq
```

will load the Kyber and BFQ I/O schedulers (see [`block/Kconfig.iosched`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/Kconfig.iosched) for details), and they should then be selectable:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] kyber bfq none
```

Look at the contents of `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/block` and `IOSCHED` settings in your kernel’s `.config` file (`/boot/config-$(uname -r)`).